# Get Facebook user album=> photos inserted into Mysql db on a website

Tags: php, facebook, photos

Can anyone help me with a step by step sample on how to get Get Facebook user album=> photos  and  inserted into Mysql db on a another website  using PHP

like some kind of import this facebook user's albums from facebook script for a website

Thanks

Comment: no one is going to write it for you, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Build a web server that can host your php and mySQL. Make sure you get a valid SSL cert.
2. Research the Graph API's album to determine what data structure to implement. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/
3. Get a facebook app configured. https://developers.facebook.com/apps
4. Play around with the graph API to understand your queries you will need to write https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
5. Use the PHP SDK to write your integration with Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/